# linking a .obj file with alink

Tags: assembly, linker, linker-errors, linker-warning

i wrote a helloworld program for win64 and converted it to a .obj file using nasm...now i have to load the resultant hello.obj file using alink but errors are cropping...

to assemble i used the command

```
   nasm -f win64 -o hello.obj helloworld.asm
```

(this executed successfully)

and to load i am writing

```
alink hello.obj
```

but the error which is continuously showing is

```
loading file hello.obj 
unknown file type
```

then once i wrote -f win32 instead of -f win64...
and then when i executed the same loading code for alink(i.e. alink hello.obj) the screen wrote

```
loading file hello.obj 
matched externs
matched comdefs
warning,no entry point specified
warning-no stack
error:target address out of frame
base=00000010, target=00000000
```

the helloworld.asm file is [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=DIEv6)

Comment: Your assembly language program is written for 32-bit Linux, so even if you sort out your object formats and linking problems, you'll end up with a program that does nothing but crash. If nobody's answered your question by the time I get home tonight, I'll write a sample Hello World in nasm-style assembly for win64 and post it with linking instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The major problem you're having with alink is that it doesn't have any 64-bit support, which is why you had to use `nasm -fwin32` to generate 32-bit object code. The second problem is that you haven't specified an entry point. Frustrating, isn't it? I wasted a lot of time with different linkers myself.

If you want to do win64 assembly with nasm, I suggest using [golink](http://www.godevtool.com/Golink.zip). It takes the light, fast, no-nonsense approach to linking. If you want to use functions from a DLL in your code, you don't need any library files -- GoLink can do all the linking using just the DLL files themselves. It'll even pull them off the system path, so you don't need to put anything in the same folder as your source code.

The next major problem you're having is that your example code isn't suited for Windows. Here's one that you can use to get started that won't crash when you run it:

```
; example64.s
; nasm -fwin64 example64.s
; golink /console example64.obj kernel32.dll msvcrt.dll

    bits 64
    default rel

    extern  GetStdHandle
    extern  WriteFile
    extern  ExitProcess
    extern  printf

section .data 
message db  'Hello, World!',10,0
msglen equ $-message
written dq      1

section .text
    global Start ; GoLink will use Start as the default entry point
Start:
    ; Use the C library to print our message
    mov rcx, message
    call    printf

    ; Now try using the Windows API
    mov rcx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    ; Use WriteFile to print our message again.
    ; Notice the calling convention for 64-bit Windows uses
    ; rcx, rdx, r8, and r9 for the first 4 non-floating point arguments
    ; and then the rest are pushed onto the stack.
    mov rcx, rax    ; HANDLE hFile
    mov rdx, message    ; LPCVOID lpBuffer
    mov r8, msglen  ; DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite
    mov r9, written ; LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    push    qword 0     ; LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    call    WriteFile

    mov rcx, 0
    call    ExitProcess
```

Assuming it's saved as example64.s, you can assemble and link it like so:

`nasm -fwin64 example64.s`

`golink /console example64.obj kernel32.dll msvcrt.dll`

Note that the reason we include kernel32.dll is for the Windows API calls (WriteFile, ExitProcess, GetStdHandle). Likewise, msvcrt.dll is for standard C library functions (i.e. printf, malloc, etc.). If you want to get really down and dirty with Win64 assembly, you'll probably want to go ahead and just use the Windows API, leaving out msvcrt.dll. You can find documentation for all the Windows API functions and data structures [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Finally, it's worth noting that a lot of the function prototypes and structures they give on MSDN are for the 32-bit Windows API, so whenever you see a DWORD, you'll probably want to use a QWORD instead.

Anyway, I hope that gets you started in the direction you want to go. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you man, i know there is much time have passed since you wrote it, but it was a BIG help, thanks a lot again.

Comment: Unfortunately this segfaults in Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use ALINK you could try this:

- to assemble a win32 program (written in 32b code!):

  ```
  nasm -f obj file_name.asm
  ```
- to assemble a win64 program (written in 64b code!):

  ```
  nasm -f win64 file_name.asm
  ```

Now, the linking process for the 32b object:

```
alink -oPE -subsys con -entry Start file_name.obj
```

Where Start is the entry point for your program, the one that you declared global.

For the 64b object, try another link-editor like goLink, as James suggested.

This should do it. Hope it works for you too!